# UIImage compressing but not resizing to max size

Tags: ios, uiimage

I have below:

```
extension UIImage{

func compressToMaxSize(bytes: Int) -> UIImage{
    var data: Data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self, 1.0)!
    var compressionRatio: CGFloat = CGFloat(bytes) / CGFloat(data.count)

    while data.count > bytes && compressionRatio > 0{
        data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self, compressionRatio)!
        compressionRatio = compressionRatio - 0.05
    }

    return UIImage(data: data)!
}
}
```

It does return an UIImage with size less than the bytes parameter, but I am suspicious, because the compressed size is about tenth of the original, even though the compression ratio was around 0.46. What am I missing here?

Comment: In the while loop I set data to UIImageJPEGRep of the original image and use the count off of that as size.

Answer (score 0):

> What am I missing here?

What you're missing is what a JPEG is.

JPEG is lossy. To implement that lossiness, it encodes the image data in a special way — where, for example, things like repeated pixels (same color) are notated in a brief shorthand. The greater the compression, the more the pixels will be considered to be repetitions of one another (exactness of color is thrown away).

Thus, the output size depends upon the image. How detailed is it? How much color repetition is there? An image of just one solid color could compress very tiny, regardless of the compression ratio.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG, where there's a table of compression ratios and resulting sizes for a typical photo: "The medium quality photo uses only 4.3% of the storage space required for the uncompressed image".

Comment: I'm using the stock images on the simulator to test, the yellow leaf one. At 1.0 compression ratio, it's 8112955 bytes using UIImageJPEGRep. At 0.95, it's 3559237 bytes. Is this an expected result? The size dropped drastically.

Comment: I don't know what "expected" even means. What it does is what it does. But that is certainly in line with the web page I sent you to.